# Android 10 Desktop mode on Linux laptop

Tags: android-10, screen-sharing

Recently I received the update to Android 10 for my LG G8s ThinQ and one of the things that I was waiting to test was the desktop mode. The desktop mode is working fine when I am connecting my phone to an external screen but when I want to use my Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) laptop as the external screen the phone doesn't recognize it and just shows the normal file transfer.

How I can use my linux laptop as the external screen and keyboard and mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notebooks usually don't have ports (HDMI, display-port) for display-input, only display-output for connecting an external monitor/TV.

If you want to remote-control your phone from your Linux laptop I recommend the software `scrcpy` to you. It let you use mouse and keyboard from a PC and see the display of the smartphone on your monitor/laptop display. The connection uses the USB cable, you only need to activate Android Developer Options and the Android Debug Bridge (adb).

Comment: Is this it? https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc/ and this is the github for it https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes that is the software I had in mind.